# Не работает пример asyncore

Tags: python, сокет

Копировал пример из [документации](https://docs.python.org/2/library/asyncore.html), переделал под 3 python и не работает, сервер запускается, клиент запускается и закрывается без ошибки даже. Объясните как работать с asyncore? Нужно подключение многих людей к 1 серверу и общение между ними.

Comment: А чего `asyncore`? Поссмотрите `asyncio` + `aiohttp`

Comment: А зачем переделывать если есть пример для 3 питона: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/asyncore.html

Comment: @IgorSergeevich а эта связка пойдет для одновременного получения сообщений сервером до 512 клиентов?

Comment: @MrLuckyTomas и даже больше

Comment: @Avernial в примере HTTP клиент, он не работает с сервером в примере, есть пример норм клиента?

Comment: А зачем переделывать? В верхнем левом углу тыкаете на комбобокс с версией и ставите, например, 3.5 -- получите код

Comment: @gil9red а я и не заметил его)

Answer (score 0):

Вот рабочий пример. Клиент из документации не соединяется с сервером из примера, потому что клиент работает с 80 портом, а сервер запускается на 8080 порту. Поэтому клиенту просто нужно указать к какому порту подключаться.

Код сервера:

```
import asyncore


class EchoHandler(asyncore.dispatcher_with_send):

    def handle_read(self):
        data = self.recv(8192)
        if data:
            self.send(data)


class EchoServer(asyncore.dispatcher):

    def __init__(self, host, port):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.create_socket()
        self.set_reuse_addr()
        self.bind((host, port))
        self.listen(5)

    def handle_accepted(self, sock, addr):
        print('Incoming connection from %s' % repr(addr))
        handler = EchoHandler(sock)

server = EchoServer('localhost', 8080)
asyncore.loop()
```

Код клиента:

```
import asyncore


class HTTPClient(asyncore.dispatcher):

    def __init__(self, host, port, path):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.create_socket()
        self.connect((host, port))
        self.buffer = bytes('GET %s HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: %s\r\n\r\n' %
                            (path, host), 'ascii')

    def handle_connect(self):
        pass

    def handle_close(self):
        self.close()

    def handle_read(self):
        print(self.recv(8192))

    def writable(self):
        return (len(self.buffer) > 0)

    def handle_write(self):
        sent = self.send(self.buffer)
        self.buffer = self.buffer[sent:]


client = HTTPClient('127.0.0.1', 8080, '/')
asyncore.loop()
```

Если клиент подключится нормально, то вы должны увидеть такое сообщение на сервере:

```
Incoming connection from ('127.0.0.1', 53168)
```